# Is the Lotus Connections 3 SPI documentation still valid for IBM Connections 4?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've noticed that the product documentation in the Lotus Connections 3 wiki is more complete than that in the Connections 4 wiki. For example, the [SPI documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus+Connections+3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Lotus_Connections_SPIs_lc3&content=pdcontent) in Lotus Connections 3 appears to be entirely missing for Connections 4.

- Is the old documentation still valid?
- Are there updates to the documentation scheduled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David are you looking at the documentation on the social business development wiki?
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc